# Where to type @Override?

Tags: java, android, vim, syntax, coding-style

in most IDEs and editors there's no consensus as to how to ident the @Override. and it's not covered in the coding style for java http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

i use exclusively vim and it creates a new indentation level. So i'm inclined to think that the correct is

```
@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
```

But every documentation shows

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
```

But most of the time, the editor autoidents that to

```
   @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
```

So, is there a 'correct' way? should i fix my java.vim syntax rules?

Comment: The question was mostly about style. i know they compile, otherwise i wouldn't be asking :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no one 'correct' way... all of them compile just fine, so they are all correct. Though, most of the cases you will see:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
```

And, that's the way I prefer, because most programmers are used to that syntax, thus it's easier to read/understand for them.

Comment: Elements of Java Style suggests that you write it this way also. http://www.ambysoft.com/books/elementsJavaStyle.html

Comment: accepting by popular demand. So, i will consider sending a patch to vim to fix that extra indentation step.

Comment: i'm still finding excuses not to prepare that vim syntax patch... but want to add this to my virtual memory: that this is also the style used in the android documentation/generated source. And also by published  Stanford classes' material, such as http://ee368.stanford.edu/Android/ViewfinderEE368/ViewfinderEE368.java

Answer (score 0):

All the ways that you have listed are equivalent. The java compiler doesn't take into account white space. So as long as the method after the annotation is the one you want, then it is correct. Now I say that because there can be other annotations or comments between @override and the method declaration.

Comment: That's why i asked for 'correct' way, using quotes :) The question is most about style.